# Largura de um elemento calculado com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Eu quero o seguinte.
Quando eu passe o mouse em cima do `li`, a div `topoMenuBarra` deixe de ser `display:none` para ser `display:block`, e a `width` da div seja equivalente ao `a` que existe dentro do `li`.

Ele está pegando como largura o `li`.
Eu já informei o `$( ".topoMenu li a" ).hover(function()` sem o `a` e não funciona.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $( ".topoMenu li a" ).hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var largura = $this.width();
  $( this ).find('.topoMenuBarra').css({
   'display':'block',
   'width': largura + 'px'
  });
 },
 function() {
  $( this ).find('.topoMenuBarra').css('display','none'); /*fazer barra desaparecer*/
 });

});
```

```css
.topoMenu li {
    font: 300 20px/20px'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}
.topoMenu li img {
    margin-right: 95px;
    margin-top: 44px
}
.topoMenu li a {
    margin-top: 62px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.topoMenuBarra{
height: 2px;
background-color: #ced1d7;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a href="/empresas">empresa</a>
 <div class="topoMenuBarra"></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é estar a usar o `.find()` que procura descendentes do `this`. Se usar `.next()` já vai funcionar pois o `topoMenuBarra` não é descendente da acora mas sim sibling. (já agora `.siblings()` também funcionaria).

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxa6zzwy/1

Use assim: `$this.next('.topoMenuBarra').css({`

Exemplo com jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $( ".topoMenu li a" ).hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var largura = $this.width();
  $this.next('.topoMenuBarra').css({
   'display':'block',
   'width': largura + 'px'
  });
 },
 function() {
  $(this).next('.topoMenuBarra').css('display','none'); /*fazer barra desaparecer*/
 });

});
```

```css
.topoMenu li {
    font: 300 20px/20px'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}
.topoMenu li img {
    margin-right: 95px;
    margin-top: 44px
}
.topoMenu li a {
    margin-top: 62px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.topoMenuBarra{
height: 2px;
background-color: #ced1d7;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="topoMenu">
<li>
    <a href="/empresas">empresa</a>
 <div class="topoMenuBarra"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

---

Na verdade isto pode ser feito só com CSS e não precisa da div em baixo.

Precisa só de: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hxa6zzwy/2/

```
.topoMenu a:hover {
   border-bottom: 4px #bbbbbb solid;
}
```

Comment: Exato cara, eu não havia percebido esse detalhe. Muito obrigado.

Comment: @FelipeStoker juntei uma variante só com CSS, acho melhor...

Comment: como eu daria uma margem nessa borda?

Comment: @FelipeStoker será no `padding-bottom`. http://jsfiddle.net/hxa6zzwy/3/

Comment: Ok, minha dúvida. Se eu clicar um pouco abaixo, ao invés de ser diretamente em cima do `a`, pode ser na própria linha, ele vai entrar no link?

Comment: @FelipeStoker a linha extra é ativada pelo `a:hover` então se a linha extra estiver visivel o click vai abrir o link.